# Is there a way to just run tags without opening and closing browser?

Tags: webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I am trying to run specific scenarios from various different feature files using tagExpression but webdriver opens and closes browser for each scenario until it finds the tag I provided. Is there a way to NOT open the browser until it finds the tag?

````
    // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
    require: ['./features/step_definitions/*.js'],
    // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    backtrace: true,
    // <string[]> ("extension:module")
    // require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    compiler: [],
    dryRun: false, // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    failFast: true, // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format,
    // optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    format: ['pretty'],
    colors: true,
    snippets: true,
    source: true, 
    profile: [], 
    strict: true,
    tagExpression: '@testone',
    timeout: 300000, ble this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
  },```
````

Answer (score 0):

Selenium session created(opening and closing browser happens at this point) for every feature file (not for scenarios). If you have some feature files that does not have any scenarios that is matching with your tag, then you can avoid opening them by using either of the two options: `exclude` or `suites` approach.

Please follow their documentation.

Examples:

```
//Not required features can be added here such that wdio ignores them  
exclude: [
        './features/**/test.feature'
    ]
```

OR

```
//Define suites and pass as part of params
suites:{
        bvt: [
            './features/BVT_Desktop.feature',
            './features/BVT_Mobile.feature',
        ]
    }
```

Comment: We have those setup. But we have lots of tags on scenarios in different features.   wanted to see if there is a way to just run the scenario/feature that matches the tag but not opening browser for a feature that does not match the tag. For example we have 200 features and about 600 scenarios. we have 10 scenarios with tag "@XXX". Now if I run the suite with that tag it will open 200 browser sessions to execute 10 scenarios. I just want 10 sessions if there is a way.